# Unable to upgrade (16.04)

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, crash

I don't seem to be able to upgrade beyond 4.4.0-81 .

Every time I do it crashes during boot and it looks like this:

[image]

I didn't find any similar issues by googling and the error is unreadable so there's no clues to follow. At least I found no clues in places I know how to look for.

Intel Core i7-4720HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz × 8
Intel onboard graphics in combination with an Nvidia GTX 980M graphics card
8GB RAM

My other computer has no issue upgrading. It's upgraded to each of the iterations since 4.4.0-81 and literally upgraded to kernel 4.4.0-89 a moment ago. It's on the team red side of things:

AMD FX9590 x8@5GHz
AMD R9 Fury X
32GB RAM

Edit:
I found by hitting alt-ctrl-F1 I was able to see the hidden text. Can anyone help now that it has been revealed? Also I really don't think it's the nvidia driver. I rebuilt it for both the working kernel and the new one and nothing changed.
[image]

Comment: You're comparing AMD with Intel+(high end) Nvidia. The former currently works entirely on the default open source drivers (performance may or may not improve with alternative proprietary drivers); the latter requires proprietary Nvidia drivers that, depending on *how* those drivers were installed, they may not build for new kernels. It seems to be the case here. Have you installed using the binary downloaded from Nvidia by any chance?

Comment: I added their repo to my update a while back. So when I run apt update it will check for new nvidia drivers. I am currently running 384.59.

Comment: So...would you know how to check if the driver is/is not building for new kernels? It may be the issue, but it could be something else too.

Comment: Depending on the repo but generally yes, it should build correctly.

Comment: Is there more info I can provide to narrow down what the problem is?

Comment: I don't think the issue is to do with the nvidia drivers. The modules are properly rebuilding on a kernel update. I just attempted updating to 4.4.0-91 and had the same issue shown in my post above. I ran `dkms status` and this is the result: http://imgur.com/a/bDWzQ

Any thoughts?

Comment: Problem still persisting with 4.4.0-92

Comment: Found more info and updated original post above. Also I'm now trying with 4.4.0-93. Again works fine on other pc. Anyone able to help now?

Answer (score 0):

After multiple more kernel updates that I couldn't get to work. I did something I didn't want to do, but technically solved the problem. I upgraded to a non LTS build. I've upgraded to 17.04 and not having problems. No idea what the problem was but it's gone now.